# Mass point delta and it's mathematical interpretation

Tags: self-study, marginal-distribution, integral

Considering a spike-and-slab prior of the form

$$w\sim\pi\mathcal{N}(0,\alpha^{-1})+(1-\pi)\delta_0$$
where $\delta_0$ is a point mass at zero, if we would like to integrate over w such that

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \pi \big(\frac{1}{2\pi\alpha^{-1}}\big)^{k/2}\exp\big(-\frac{\|w\|^2}{2\alpha^{-1}}\big)   +(1-\pi)\delta_0 dw$$

I was having problem doing the second part, namely

$$II=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1-\pi)\delta_0 dw$$

I was wondering what exactly is the mathematical interpretation of mass point is? Is it a constant or should it be zero?

Comment: what's your problem? The integral of $\delta_0$ over any interval including 0 is 1, thus $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1-\pi)\delta_0 dw=(1-\pi)$$

Comment: So mass point $\delta$ is same as the dirac delta function?

Comment: yes, it's the same.

Comment: @DeltaIV I also was wondering if you have any suggestions for the following integral:

$$II=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1-\pi)\delta_0 d\pi$$ 

Although $\delta_0$ is a function of $w$, the probability distribution of w is a function of \pi, so it can’t be taken out of integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral of the Dirac delta centered in 0 $\delta_0$ over any interval *I* including 0 is 1, and 0 if *I* doesn't include 0. I'm not very familiar with spike and slab priors, but **if** $\pi$ is a constant independent of the parameter $w$, then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1-\pi)\delta_0 dw=(1-\pi)$$

Comment: A concise summary as an excuse for the username joke: $$\int_{C} \delta_4(w)dw = \mathbb{1}_{4 \in C}$$.

Comment: @eric_kernfeld I like the concise summary, though I preferred to go for the lengthy explanation since the OP seemed not to be familiar with this kind of shortcuts. But I don't understand, what's the username joke?

Comment: Maybe it's lame, but you're $\delta_4$!

Comment: @eric_kernfeld :'-D you're right, I didn't make the connection because the origin of that username is completely different...but good point anyway!